# SAS - How to determine the number of variables in a used range?

Tags: sas

I imagine what I'm asking is pretty basic, but I'm not entirely certain how to do it in SAS.

Let's say that I have a range of variables, or an array, x1-xn. I want to be able to run a program that uses the number of variables within that range as part of its calculation. But I want to write it in such a way that, if I add variables to that range, it will still function.

Essentially, I want to be able to create a variable that if I have x1-x6, the variable value is '6', but if I have x1-x7, the value is '7'.

I know that :

```
var1=n(of x1-x6)
```

will return the number of non-missing numeric variables.. but I want this to work if there are missing values.

I hope I explained that clearly and that it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things.

First off,  when you put a range like you did:

```
x1-x7
```

That will *always* evaluate to seven items, whether or not those variables exist.  That simply evaluates to

```
x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7
```

So it's not very interesting to ask how many items are in that, unless you're generating that through a macro (and if you are, you probably can have that macro indicate how many items are in it).

But the range `x1--x7` or `x:` both are more interesting problems, so we'll continue.

---

The *easiest* way to do this is, if the variables are all of a single type (but an unknown type), is to create an array, and then use the `dim` function.

```
data _null_;
  x3='ABC';
  array _temp x1-x7;
  count = dim(_temp);
  put count=;
run;
```

That doesn't work, though, if there are multiple types (numeric and character) at hand.  If there are, then you need to do something more complex.

The next easiest solution is to combine `nmiss` and `n`.  This works if they're all numeric, or if you're tolerant of the log messages this will create.

```
data _null_;
  x3='ABC';
  count = nmiss(of x1-x7) + n(of x1-x7);
  put count=;
run;
```

`nmiss` is number of missing, plus `n` is number of nonmissing numeric.  Here `x3` is counted with the `nmiss` group.

Unfortunately, there is not a `c` version of `n`, or we'd have an easier time with this (combining `c` and `cmiss`).  You could potentially do this in a macro function, but that would get a bit messy.

Fortunately, there is a third option that is tolerant of character variables: combining `countw` with `catx`.  Then:

```
data _null_;
  x3='ABC';
  x4=' ';
  count = countw(catq('dm','|',of x1-x7),'|','q');
  put count=;
run;
```

This will count all variables, numeric or character, with no conversion notes.

What you're doing here is concatenating all of the variables together with a delimiter between, so `[x1]|[x2]|[x3]...`, and then counting the number of "words" in that string defining word as thing delimited by "|".  Even missing values will create something - so `.|.|ABC|.|.|.|.` will have 7 "words".

The 'm' argument to CATQ tells it to even include missing values (spaces) in the concatenation.  The 'q' argument to COUNTW tells it to ignore delimiters inside quotes (which CATQ adds by default).

If you use a version before CATQ is available (sometime in 9.2 it was added I believe), then you can use CATX, but you lose the modifiers, meaning you have more trouble with empty strings and embedded delimiters.

Comment: The COUNTW(CATX()) trick doesn't work for empty character variables. Try adjusting it to `count=countw(catx('|',of x1--x7),'|')+cmiss(' ',of x1-character-x7)-1`

Comment: To fix treatment of embedded delimiters adjust the modifiers on both CATQ and COUNTW functions. `countw(catq('dmas','|',of x1--x7),'|','mq')`

Comment: Yeah, I might as well add that mightn't I since I switched to CATQ anyway.  Don't need any other arguments for CATQ, just adding 'q' to COUNTW does it.  CATQ always quotes things with embedded delimiters.

Comment: BTW you're always welcome to add these in directly if it's a trivial thing like this and doesn't change the overall answer, if you want.